# Calculate projected compound interest based on many short term loans

Tags: finance

I have a dataset of many short term bitcoin loans (duration <= 2 days) all with different interest rates, a fee to the broker and an amount.

How can I calculate the overall interest rate achieved so far?

Also how can I project these loans forward to estimate the interest rate which may be achieved over 356 days (for example)?

The data looks like this:

```
Currency        Rate        Amount      Duration    Interest    Fee         Earned      Open                Close
BTC             0.001271    0.06704019  0.2596875   0.00002213  -0.00000331 0.00001882  2017-05-10 08:20:53 2017-05-10 14:34:50
BTC             0.001271    0.10156546  0.0099537   0.00000129  -0.00000019 0.0000011   2017-05-10 08:24:15 2017-05-10 08:38:35
BTC             0.000799    0.10154408  0.30996527  0.00002515  -0.00000377 0.00002138  2017-05-10 00:49:56 2017-05-10 08:16:17
BTC             0.00123189  0.06704006  0.00171296  0.00000015  -0.00000002 0.00000013  2017-05-10 08:04:58 2017-05-10 08:07:26
BTC             0.00118601  0.06703824  0.02690972  0.00000214  -0.00000032 0.00000182  2017-05-10 07:24:01 2017-05-10 08:02:46
BTC             0.001       0.06703823  0.00003472  0.00000001  0           0.00000001  2017-05-10 07:19:10 2017-05-10 07:19:13
BTC             0.00091949  0.18783711  0.00770833  0.00000134  -0.0000002  0.00000114  2017-05-10 06:52:46 2017-05-10 07:03:52
BTC             0.000924    0.18778117  0.37927083  0.00006581  -0.00000987 0.00005594  2017-05-09 21:27:21 2017-05-10 06:33:30
BTC             0.00087866  0.73390906  0.00434027  0.0000028   -0.00000042 0.00000238  2017-05-10 06:05:25 2017-05-10 06:11:40
BTC             0.002       0.6191182   2.00019675  0.00247671  -0.0003715  0.00210521  2017-05-08 05:40:34 2017-05-10 05:40:51
BTC             0.000887    0.11268024  0.06361111  0.00000636  -0.00000095 0.00000541  2017-05-10 03:55:14 2017-05-10 05:26:50
BTC             0.000798    0.1126746   0.07363425  0.00000663  -0.00000099 0.00000564  2017-05-10 01:49:48 2017-05-10 03:35:50
BTC             0.0012      0.00110366  0.52340277  0.0000007   -0.0000001  0.0000006   2017-05-09 13:01:17 2017-05-10 01:34:59
BTC             0.000902    0.11156788  0.02869212  0.00000289  -0.00000043 0.00000246  2017-05-10 00:13:02 2017-05-10 00:54:21
BTC             0.000862    0.10153151  0.16881944  0.00001478  -0.00000221 0.00001257  2017-05-09 20:36:10 2017-05-10 00:39:16
BTC             0.00580858  0.11047664  2.00060185  0.00128381  -0.00019257 0.00109124  2017-05-07 23:27:13 2017-05-09 23:28:05
BTC             0.0012      0.01142117  0.32305555  0.00000443  -0.00000066 0.00000377  2017-05-09 13:01:17 2017-05-09 20:46:29
BTC             0.00089641  0.17634749  0.06498842  0.00001028  -0.00000154 0.00000874  2017-05-09 19:10:50 2017-05-09 20:44:25
BTC             0.0012      0.1015      0.30427083  0.00003707  -0.00000556 0.00003151  2017-05-09 13:01:16 2017-05-09 20:19:25
BTC             0.000994    0.17634535  0.01427083  0.00000251  -0.00000037 0.00000214  2017-05-09 15:53:32 2017-05-09 16:14:05
BTC             0.0012      0.17632498  0.11320601  0.00002396  -0.00000359 0.00002037  2017-05-09 13:01:15 2017-05-09 15:44:16
BTC             0.0028545   0.14656802  1.50329861  0.00062894  -0.00009434 0.0005346   2017-05-08 01:33:36 2017-05-09 13:38:21
BTC             0.0012      0.0055882   0.00016203  0.00000001  0           0.00000001  2017-05-09 13:01:16 2017-05-09 13:01:30
BTC             0.001353    0.55207035  0.00005787  0.00000005  0           0.00000005  2017-05-09 12:36:07 2017-05-09 12:36:12
BTC             0.001194    0.06114588  0.07075231  0.00000517  -0.00000077 0.0000044   2017-05-09 09:47:04 2017-05-09 11:28:57
BTC             0.000994    0.49087955  0.09768518  0.00004767  -0.00000715 0.00004052  2017-05-09 08:25:42 2017-05-09 10:46:22
BTC             0.00149663  0.06114367  0.02826388  0.00000259  -0.00000038 0.00000221  2017-05-09 09:02:22 2017-05-09 09:43:04
BTC             0.00118293  0.06114365  0.00020833  0.00000002  0           0.00000002  2017-05-09 08:35:47 2017-05-09 08:36:05
BTC             0.000995    0.06114364  0.00003472  0.00000001  0           0.00000001  2017-05-09 08:31:20 2017-05-09 08:31:23
BTC             0.000994    0.06114358  0.00085648  0.00000006  0           0.00000006  2017-05-09 08:25:42 2017-05-09 08:26:56
BTC             0.0029      0.55183057  0.14155092  0.00022653  -0.00003397 0.00019256  2017-05-09 04:47:31 2017-05-09 08:11:21
BTC             0.00654001  0.54748561  1.42762731  0.00511171  -0.00076675 0.00434496  2017-05-07 18:19:54 2017-05-09 04:35:41
```

Comment: To do that, you'll have to make a bunch of assumptions: does it happen in 2 day cycles? If not, do funds get re-loaned instantly? If not, how long in between? Will all of them be paid back? If not: what risk do you want to include? The hard part is figuring out all these questions. After that it's mainly just playing around in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Ah yes I see, so I think id need to looka t the open/close position times and calculate the average of how quickly funds were re-loaned. And Id assume they would all be paid back